# Is there a way to have a ServiceStack metadata page show all the options for an enum request or response property

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to be able to have the code below

```
    [Route("/Incidents", "Get")]
public class GetViewConfig
{
    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public FilterType Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterType
{
    IsBetween,
    Is,
    IsNot
}

public class GetViewConfigResponse
{
    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class ViewConfigService : Service
{
    public object Get(GetViewConfig request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Show all the values for the FilterType on the metadata page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not on the metadata pages, but you can view this using the [Swagger API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API#wiki-swagger-attributes) and the `[ApiAllowableValues]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Api("Service Description")]
[Route("/swagger/{Name}", "GET", Summary = @"GET Summary", Notes = "GET Notes")]
public class MyRequestDto
{
    [ApiMember(Name="Name", Description = "Name Description", 
               ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    [ApiAllowableValues("Name", typeof(Color))] //Enum
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! I'm going to try this out and then circle back.

Comment: +1 I realise that this is an old post, but after adding this attribute to my service it seems like the metadata page generation now takes this into account as I can see a lit of allowable values on my metadata page which has been generated from my enum class.